What does 閣 mean in "愛情你比我想的閣較偉大"?
I'm confused what 閣 means in the song title "愛情你比我想的閣較偉大" by the band 茄子蛋. When I look it up in a dictionary, I get things like "pavilion" or "chamber", which don't make sense to me.
As an aside, is 愛情 exclusively a noun, or can it also act as a verb? Could you read the song title as "Loving You is Greater Than I Imagined", or must you read it is "Love, You are Greater Than I Imagined"? It is listed as a noun in every dictionary I check; I am wondering if it is ever casually or colloquially used as a verb.

You forgot to mention that the language of the song is in Taiwanese Hokkien. 閣 and 閣較 have Hokkien-specific usages.

閣較 is Hokkienese, this online dictionary describes it as equivalent to 更加 in Mandarin. 更加 means "more", "of greater magnitude".
愛情 is always a noun in Mandarin, I would assume it is the same in Hokkienese.
想 means to think.
The song title is addressing Love as if it were a person: Love, you are Greater Than I Thought.
However, in the music video subtitles it appears as "Oh love, you are greater than I imagined" which is a less literal translation.

茄子蛋 is Taiwanese, specializes in singing Taiwanese.
Taiwanese is derived from Hokkien.
Hokkien is the local language of Fujian (referred to as 閩Min).
The Hokkien and Taiwaness language do NOT have a standard text to record what they say, and can only be approximated in traditional Chinese words.
If you want to learn traditional Chinese, it's best NOT to learn it through his songs.
Even pure Chinese people may not be able to fully understand Hokkien.
There are some things you might get confused about:
每一擺 = 每一次
攏予我 = 都讓我
袂後悔 = 不會後悔
內底 = 裡面/其中之一
上水的彼個 = 最美的那一個
毋 = 不
攏怪你 = 都怪你
行入了 = 走入了/進入了
你我著愛 = 我就要/必須
閣較 = 更加
你予我 = 你給我
這世人 = 這輩子
愛你愛甲 = 愛你愛到
白目眉 = 白眉毛(形容蒼老)
毋 = 不
予你 = 給你
